# Project crash with lots of things on .pro, non referenced though

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qmake

I have a Qt5 project based on qmake.

`main.cpp` is the following:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The project seems to build fine. However when I run it, it will crash. That's strange, right?

What could explain that is the bunch of files I added to the project .pro file.

Anyway, if that files are not referenced in the main.cpp, would that cause any trouble? I would not expect.

Context: I'm trying to build a small part of a bigger project and so I added all kinds of things in this project until it finally build.

I already deleted .pro.user and files created during build and tried to rebuild everything again.

And even the following will also crash

```
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are "lots of things on .pro" ? The previous title was also rather unclear

Comment: Sorry, previous title was totally wrong. It was for another question. I tried to explain *lots of things* in the question, meaning many files from a bigger project

Comment: Just rebuild (after cleaning up everything) your whole new project. Or create the new testing project in a whole new directly that has nothing to do with the old project and then build your new project.

Comment: Already cleared everything, even restarted Windows. Still crash.

Comment: Just because something is "not referenced in main.cpp" does not mean it doesn't run. Statics and globals will run before `main()`. Use a debugger.

Comment: That's the answer. A static in the base class being initialized with a value defined in the derived class, looks like a problem.

Comment: Running your application through a debugger usually gives hints on where a crash happens.